# MySql whole database (tables and entities) deleted with backups. Is there any way to recreate it.

Tags: php, mysql, database, entity-framework, codeigniter

I am working on a web project using php CodeIgniter framework. I used lots of tables and entities in my project database. But unfortunately the database is deleted from my localhost and so the backups.

Now it is very time consuming to create the tables and all the entities for my database that i used for my project.

Is there any way to automatically create the tables and entities from my php source code?

Comment: I don't think there is way to do it as I Know

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I don't know if you can find a way to do this, but if you are not already using git (or some other version control system), now would be an excellent time to start, by putting your table creation statements as well as your other source code in it

Comment: The data is _not_ stored anywhere else, so there is no way to somehow magically recreate it once it is deleted. Except for hard disk forensic which might be able to recreate the files, especially the backup files. But that is a hard task and typically you won't be able to retrieve _all_ of your data. If you want to give it a try yourself then you have to deactivate that drive immediately and check the raw sectors which hopefully did not get overwritten in the mean time. There is assistance software for that, but typically this is a pro job and will take more time than recreating things.

Comment: once i also lost my mysql data + my project files. due to hard disk fail. i could not recover them. to avoid this you can backup your data to dropbox or google drive

Comment: We clearly have a very different understanding of the term 'backup'

Comment: check hard drive for errors http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/guide-to-using-check-disk-in-windows-vista/

Comment: I tried to recover deleted file. Search on google a lot and at least post here. May be this is my bad luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually if you put your sql codes, to create the tables if they don´t exist, then it is possible to automatically create the tables and entities from your php source code, when the database was deleted.

For example. Try select from… else create table… and retry select… Something like that…